# Dynamically print input field and radio buttons on change

Tags: jquery

Problem:
I would like to kindly ask for assistance how you can include input fields and radio buttons depending on a previous choice you make for radio buttons.

jQuery code:

```
<script src="./js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
    {
        $("input[name='authors']").change(function()
        {
            if(this.checked) 
            {
                if(this.value == 1) 
                {
                    $("#choice-1").show();
                    $("#choice-2").hide();
                }
                else if (this.value == 2)
                {
                    $("#choice-2").show();
                    $("#choice-1").hide();
                }
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

HTML code:

```
<label class="radio"><input type="radio" name="authors" id="authors" value="1">1 author</label> 
<label class="radio"><input type="radio" name="authors" id="authors" value="2">2 authors</label>

<div id="choice-1" style="display: none;">

    <label class="control-label">Gender:</label>

    <label class="radio"><input type="radio" name="FirstGender" id="FirstGender" value="1">Man</label>
    <label class="radio"><input type="radio" name="FirstGender" id="FirstGender" value="2">Woman</label>

</div>

<div id="choice-2" style="display: none;">

    <label class="control-label">Gender:</label>
    <label class="radio"><input type="radio" name="FirstGender" id="FirstGender" value="1">Man</label> 
    <label class="radio"><input type="radio" name="FirstGender" id="FirstGender" value="2">Woman</label>

    <label class="control-label">Gender:</label>
    <label class="radio"><input type="radio" name="SecondGender" id="SecondGender" value="1">Man</label> 
    <label class="radio"><input type="radio" name="SecondGender" id="SecondGender" value="2">Woman</label>

</div>
```

Desired function:
If I click on the radio button 1 Author, then 1 input textfield should be generated with a headline called "Author name" and 2 radio buttons (Man / Woman) with the headline "Gender". Similar approach goes to 2 author (see comments in the code).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: where is your HTML with input fields, post them. Do they dynamically generate?

Comment: Where do you intend to get the author info from? Database, External html or xml which one?

Comment: I have added an explanation to the desired function. I simply want to generate 1 or 2 input textfield and 2 or 4 radio buttons depending on what choice the user makes.

Comment: You simply want us to do your work, without showing any effort of doing it by your own!

Comment: @gdoron Take a deep breath, I am more than willing to show effort but the entire idea with this forum and this question is to get help when you have tried everything else. You don't have to waste time on this if you feel that I am not putting any effort. No one forced you here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("input[name='authors']").change(function() {

    $('div[id^=choice]').hide();
    $('div#choice-' + this.value).show();

});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/thecodeparadox/g3j8W/1/)**

Comment: `this.checked` is always true in the `change` event with `radio buttons`, test it.

Comment: I highly appreciate your code and your time to help me solve this issue. But I have to be honest and admit openly that I am not at a certain level where I can understand your code. I have updated the jQuery and HTML code to hopefully make it more clear what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You could put them in the html and wrap them in hidden divs.

```
<div id="choice-1" style="display: none>
   <!--your inputs for first choice -->
</div>


<div id="choice-2" style="display: none>
   <!--your inputs for second choice -->
</div>

if ($("input[name='authors']:checked").val() == '1') {
   $("#choice-1").show();
   $("#choice-2").hide();
} else if ($("input[name='authors']:checked").val() == '2') {
   $("#choice-2").show();
   $("#choice-1").hide();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you want to dynamically add input field and radio buttons like this:

```
var input = $('<input type="text">'),
    radio = $('<input type="radio">'),
    label = $('<label>'),
    output = $('#output'),
    authorLabel = label.clone().html('Author').appendTo(output),
    author = input.clone().attr('id','author').appendTo(output),
    rdmLabel = label.clone().html('Male').appendTo(output),
    rdm = radio.clone().attr({'name':'gender',value:'M'}).appendTo(output)
    rdfLabel = label.clone().html('Female').appendTo(output),
    rdf = radio.clone().attr({'name':'gender',value:'F'}).appendTo(output);
```